# How to center content in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, flexbox

I'm having an issue on my project where the content is not aligning vertically in the flexbox. We have a fluid responsive page that needs to center all items within the flexbox via %'s. in the example below we've set a fixed pixel height just so you can play with it.

I have tried a ton of different methods for hours..

```
body{
  margin:0px auto;

}
/* top bar navigation */
.topBoxNav {
  background:red;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'League Gothic';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.topBoxNav li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.topBoxNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="" alt="top Nav">
  <ul class="topBoxNav">
    <li><a href="">Box1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Box2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Box3</a></li>
  </ul>     
</nav>
```

example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iwDdy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, realize that the one that has the `display: flex` property is your `ul`, not your `li` elements, so you have two options here:

1) Give your `li` elements `display: flex` and add `align-items: center` to it and `justify-content: center`

You will get something like this:

```
.topBoxNav li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;

  align-items center
  -moz-align-items center
  -ms-flex-align center
  -webkit-align-items center

  justify-content center
  -moz-justify-content center
  -ms-flex-pack center
  -webkit-justify-content center
}
```

2) Give your `li` elements `line-height` equal to the `height`, in this case `50px` and `vertical-align: middle`.

You will have something like this:

```
.topBoxNav li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Both ways will work :)

Comment: thanks that did the trick of adding:

    display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;

    justify-content: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;

to the LI element as you described, this also keeps things responsive instead of the line-height having a specified pixel.